# Zend Framework 2 change layout based on domain

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap, view, rendering, zend-framework2

For a part of my network with 4 similar websites (same code, but different layouts) I would like to create one application with 'Zend Framework 2' to control these 4 websites in one app. This application should take a look which domain is requested and render the right main layout and view layout for the requested website.

My thoughts about this is to write a plugin who set a variable for layout/view at the time when bootstrap is executed.

Is this right or is it better to do this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that a plugin or a small module that listens to the dispatch or bootstrap events would serve you best. Rob Allen has a complete list of the ZF2 events  [in this post](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/a-list-of-zf2-events/). Empirio Lab [have a concise post](http://lab.empirio.no/how-to-attach-mvc-events-in-zf2.html) with the relevant Module configuration on their site if you choose to go that way.